# Security policy `PDF' in the Laravel Sail container when using Imagick

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I would like to convert a PDF into a PNG. I would use Imagick for this. My Laravel instance runs via the Laravel Sail docker container. Unfortunately, I get an error message when using Imagick:

`Attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy PDF @ error/constitute.c/IsCoderAuthorized/421`

To solve the problem I would have to change my PDF policy in the file `/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml` to: `<policy domain="coder" rights="read | write" pattern="PDF" />`. To do this, I go into the container with `docker exec -it 123abc bash`. The problem now is that I don't have an editor like nano or vim in the container. My question: How can I install an editor in the container? Or is there perhaps another way, library to solve the PDF policy?

**Note:** I see in the docker-compose file that a Dockerfile is specified. But I don't have a Dockerfile in my directory. Would it be possible to create one and enter an apt install command?

Comment: Can't you copy out the policy.xml file to some other system, modify it, then put it back into this system?

Comment: @fmw42 Hi! That is a very good idea. I tried but i got permission problems. `p: cannot create regular file '/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml': Permission denied`

Comment: Looks like an OS permission issue.  Was that on copy out or the move in?  Are you doing as root/owner?

Comment: @fmw42 I have just tried it with docker exec instead of "sail shell" and was able to copy the file. So I went into the container with docker exec and copied the file to my laravel root project directory with cp (`root@9bf02aae50ad:/var/www/html# cp /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml .`). Edited there and then copied the file back. That worked for now. but unfortunately i still have the error. maybe i have to restart the container now?

Comment: @fmw42 since i did that my app doesn't work anymore :-( i'll rebuild with sail build.